# Считать файл в массив строк, одно слово = элемент массива

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Считываю текст из файла следующим методом:

```
public static String[] Input (String filename){
     String[] text = null;
        try {
            String str = null;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text = str.split(" ");
                for (String it : text) {
                    System.out.printf("%s\t", it);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("IO error!" + exc);
        }
        return text;
}
```

однако в массив считывается только последний абзац. Как сделать так, чтобы считывался весь текст, при чем один элемент массива содержал только одно слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При считывании каждой строки Вы заменяете весь массив:

```
text = str.split(" ");
```

вместо этого надо добавлять новые слова в конец массива.
Это можно сделать непосредственно расширяя массив:

```
//определяем пустой массив изначально
String[] text = new String[0];
try {
    String str = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //получаем новые слова
        String[] newWords = str.split(" ");
        //создаем расширенный массив
        String[] result = new String[text.length + newWords.length];
        //копируем элементы в массив
        System.arraycopy(text, 0, result, 0, text.length);
        System.arraycopy(newWords, 0, result, text.length, newWords.length);
        //присваиваем результирующий массив текущему
        text = result;
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException exc) {
    System.out.println("IO error!" + exc);
}
return text;
```

Но этот подход требует выделения памяти на каждом шаге. Возможно будет оптимальнее использовать для хранения данных список:

```
//объявляем список
List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
//...
//добавляем новые элементы
text.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
//...
//если нужно можно получить массив слов
return text.toArray(new String[text.size()]);
```

Comment: а можно ли использовать для хранения список списков, и считать из файла так, чтобы каждый новый абзац текста был новым элементом списка списков?

Comment: @ВикторияПушкина можно :) Для каждой строки (абзац это же строка, правильно?) нужно будет создавать список слов и добавлять их в список списков.

Comment: где то необходимо заранее указывать количество абзацов=списков, или это как-то зациклить можно?

Comment: @ВикторияПушкина если создается именно список, a-la `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOLists = new ArrayList<>();` то не нужно. При добавлении он автоматически расширяется.